# How do I move an email to a different folder using zend_mail and zend_mail_storage_imap?

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, zend-mail

I'm using these libraries for an email application I'm building.

```
$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($imap);

if (strpos($storage->getMessage($i),'chocolate') !== FALSE ) 

{
        //Move to chocolate folder here
}
```

Also, is there a way to put incoming emails from this sender to automatically go into the chocolate folder from now on?  ...similar to how you can build labels in gmail and all mail from that sender will automatically go into that folder in the future.

I'm still new to zend, I'm going to go relook at the documentation again.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tricky is true.

```
$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($imap);
if (strpos($storage->getMessage($i),'chocolate') !== FALSE ){
    //Move to chocolate folder here
    $messageUniqueId = $storage->getUniqueId($i);
    $currentMessageId = $storage->getNumberByUniqueId($messageUniqueId);
    $storage->moveMessage($messageUniqueId, 'chocolate');
}
```

Comment: FYI: It may work if you use $i directly in moveMessage. However, if a second message should be deleted and $i comes from a loop then the id is probaly wrong. Because of this you have to use the current id that you get with the code of Elzo.

Comment: Barney has removed my edit: I think the last line should be $storage->moveMessage($currentMessageId, 'chocolate'); I just tried it with unique id and with gmail what did not work. Look at comment at Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap->getNumberByUniqueId($id). Or is $currentMessageId just for decoration? Assuming Zend 1.12.